# How to find the maximum average of all fields grouped by ID in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

So I have a massive table with over 50 fields and I need to find the maximum average of each field by ID. My table looks something like this:

```
    +----+--------+--------+-----+---------+
    | ID | field1 | field2 | ... | field50 |
    +----+--------+--------+-----+---------+
    | 1  | 234    | 12     | ... | 634     |
    +----+--------+--------+-----+---------+
    | 2  | 1      | 69     | ... | 34      |
    +----+--------+--------+-----+---------+
    | 3  | 512    | 1000   | ... | 420     |
    +----+--------+--------+-----+---------+
    | 4  | 11     | 69     | ... | 34      |
    +----+--------+--------+-----+---------+
    | 3  | 522    | 1337   | ... | 78      |
    +----+--------+--------+-----+---------+
    | 2  | 18     | 698    | ... | 348     |
    +----+--------+--------+-----+---------+
    | 3  | 32     | 1910   | ... | 40      |
    +----+--------+--------+-----+---------+
```

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this. Right now, I'm trying to take maximums from a sub-query containing the averages of each ID. With the example table above, the sub-query should return something like:

```
    +----+-------+-------+-----+-------+
    | ID | avg1  | avg2  | ... | avg50 |
    +----+-------+-------+-----+-------+
    | 1  | 234   | 12    | ... | 634   |
    +----+-------+-------+-----+-------+
    | 2  | 9.5   | ~990  | ... | 191   |
    +----+-------+-------+-----+-------+
    | 3  | ~355  | ~1416 | ... | 538   |
    +----+-------+-------+-----+-------+
    | 4  | 11    | 69    | ... | 34    |
    +----+-------+-------+-----+-------+
```

And the final result should return something like:

```
    +-----------+-----------+-----+------------+
    | MAX(avg1) | MAX(avg2) | ... | MAX(avg50) |
    +-----------+-----------+-----+------------+
    | ~355      | ~1416     | ... | 634        |
    +-----------+-----------+-----+------------+
```

Right now, my SQL looks like this:

```
    SELECT MAX(avg1), MAX(avg2), ... , MAX(avg50)
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, AVG(field1) AS avg1, AVG(field2) AS avg2, ... , 
    AVG(field50) AS avg50
        FROM table
        GROUP BY ID
        AS subquery
    )
```

However, I'm getting odd syntax errors within the sub-query as a LIMIT statement seems to be added on to the end of the sub-query and things get messed up. I'm relatively new to SQL and am not sure if my current method is the best way to go about things either.

If someone can help me make it work by fixing my code or provide a better solution where I don't have to enter the names of 50+ fields a brajillion times, that would be greatly appreciated.

If you need additional clarification as to what I'm trying to do, feel free to drop a comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax is wrong Put `AS subquery` out of the inner query as below

```
SELECT MAX(avg1), MAX(avg2), ... , MAX(avg50)
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, AVG(field1) AS avg1, AVG(field2) AS avg2, ... , 
    AVG(field50) AS avg50
        FROM table
        GROUP BY ID
    ) AS subquery
```

Comment: This works great! However, do you know if it's possible to make it so that I won't need to type out all 50+ fields? I thought maybe AVG(\*) or MAX(\*) would work but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: No you have to write all column there is no other way. If you got your answer please accept and upvote @StevenRedding

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the quick reply.